# CSS target selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to display `p` tag "This is my answer" when you click on anchor tag "Click me" with just `CSS`? I know I can put `p` tag after `anchor` tag and make it work but I was wondering if there is a way to make it work with the code below?

```
  <ul>
     <li>
        <div>
           <a href="one" id="one"> Click me </a>
        </div>
     </li>
        <div class="info">
           <p> This is my answer </p>
        </div>
   </ul>


li {
    list-style: none;
}

.info {
    display:none;
  }

.info:target {
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwep64bd/2/

Comment: People need to start using snippets in the question instead of linking to outside fiddle sites. Especially when it comes to very simple examples like this. Please make a snippet in the question.

Comment: Can your HTML attributes be modified (without modifying the order of elements or their type)?

Comment: @Ray: Ok then add `id="info"` to the `div` tag and change the `href` of the `a` to `#info`. That should do what you need without the need for any jQuery/JS etc. I can't see any reason why you would need `href='one'` when it isn't meant to redirect the user to any other page. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwep64bd/4/) is a sample with the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a CSS-only documented hack to control elements with a hidden checkbox. This definitely seems to cross the boundaries of "should", but sure, it's possible.

For more reading: https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

```css
 li {
  list-style: none;
 }

 label.link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 div.info {
  display: none;
 }

 #toggle-1 {
  display: none;
 }

 #toggle-1:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <label class="link" for="toggle-1">Click Me</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
    <div class="info">
        <p>
            This is my answer
        </p>
    </div>
</ul>
```